# About copy constructor and returning objects by value

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

First of all, I am not at all an experienced C++ programmer, I am just trying to pass my OOP exam. It is not very clear for me when the copy constructor is called. I knew that there are some "special" cases when giving argument by value to a functions, and when returning by value. Here, where I give arguments by value to `void F(A x)` everything happens as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A(int x = 0)    {
        x = x;
        cout<<"Constructor "<<x<<endl;    }
    ~A(){
        cout<<"Destructor "<<endl;    }

    A(const A&o){
        x = o.x;
        cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
    }
};

A F(){
    A a;
    return a;
}

void F(A x){
}

int main()
{
    //A obj(F());
    A a;
    F(a);
}
///
```

The output is:

```
Constructor 0
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

Because the `Constructor 0` is showed when declaring `A a`, the copy constructor and the destructor are showed because of the function call, cause the parameter is passed by value, and the final destructor is the destructor for `a`.

It is not very clear for me why in the next case the behaviour is so different:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A(int x = 0)    {
        x = x;
        cout<<"Constructor "<<x<<endl;    }
    ~A(){
        cout<<"Destructor "<<endl;    }

    A(const A&o){
        x = o.x;
        cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
    }
};

A F(){
    A a;
    return a;
}

void F(A x){
}

int main()
{
   A obj(F());

}
///
```

Now, the output is:

```
Constructor 0
Destructor
```

It seems like only the `A a` inside the `A F()` is called. Why isn't the copy constructor called when calling `F()`? Doesn't it return by value, isn't the copy constructor called ? Moreover, when declaring `A obj(F())` why isn't the copy constructor called at leas for `obj` ?

Comment: *It is not very clear for me why in the next case the behaviour is so different:* -- Before C++ 11, asking "how many times is the copy constructor called?" was a trick question.  It may still be a trick question.  You could take the same compiler, and depending on the compiler options used, you would get a different answer / output.  So the answer to "how many times is the copy constructor called?" -- It depends.  BTW, I like your last name :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because the compiler will "optimize" (it's actually told by the standard now to do so) the copy away and instead directly construct your `A` in the place where the function would return it to.

That's called [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (well actually NRVO, "named return value optimization", in your case as explained in that link)

Comment: so my compiler "cheats" ? If it respected the rules, those copy constructors would have been called like I said, am I right ?

Comment: No, I edited the answer. Since c++17 your compiler has to omit a copy/move, before that, it was just an optimization it was allowed to do.

Comment: @alexMcKenzie No. As mentioned in the answer - the compiler is required to elide the copy, by the newest C++ standards.

Comment: @alexMcKenzie Your compiler is following _the rules_ of the standard.  By "cheats", might you be saying that it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: @DrewDormann At school they didn't tell us about copy elision, they told us that when passing and returning by value the copy constructor is called. But I think I got it now, thank you.

Comment: @alexMcKenzie -- You should still write the code as-if the copy constructor will be called.  The copy elision is not fully under your control.  Maybe that's what the teacher was trying to point out.